# Simple MRP system in Excel-based bills of materials

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, inventory-software

Back in 2003 when I started my manufacturing company, I set up the bills of materials (BoMs) in Excel, my favorite tool.  What this means is each discrete component was a row in a worksheet (part number, description, cost, vendor, etc), and I constructed assembly BoMs in additional worksheets by linking directly to the original components.  This meant, for example, if the cost of a part changed it filtered back through all the assemblies that used the part, right up to the final SKU BoMs.  If you were any kind of an Excel weenie, as I was and am, it was the most obvious way to set up your bills of materials.

I've been using this spreadsheet for 18 years now.  This kind of thing is normally done with some kind of inventory management software, but we tried that some years ago, and it didn't work out.  Using an inventory management system is very cumbersome for a small company like mine.  The spreadsheet works fine for now, though adding new SKUs can be a headache.

Anyway, one of the key features of an inventory MRP (material requirements planning) system is the ability to immediately determine all the assemblies and SKUs that use a particular part.  We need to do that now.  In these days of shortages and supply chain issues, we are often finding ourselves without a part, say a screw or something, and we need to be able to quickly report all the SKUs that use that part, so we can show them as being out of stock to our customers and sales people.  Is there a way I can do this with Excel?

Let me run through the spreadsheet structure:

- **Components worksheet**: each row describes an individual component;
- **Assembly worksheets**: assemblies are defined as lists of components,
  and the costs are summed to represent the cost of the assembly.  An
  assembly can include components or other assemblies in its BoM. There
  are multiple assembly worksheets.
- **SKU worksheet**: the SKU assemblies are simply the top level
  assemblies; there is only one SKU worksheet.

So I'm looking for a way to query the spreadsheet with, say, a component or assembly part number, and get a listing of all the assemblies and SKUs (or maybe just the SKUs) that rely on that part number.

Is this something that I can do without a lot of arcane coding?

Comment: As with most answers, it depends. You can do a lot with the newest excel formulas. But this will require you have the latest version, or migrate to the online version (which is free for personal use).

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky that I have a background in Manufacturing as well as Excel and Coding. Otherwise I may not have been able to make it through your question to sort out what exactly you needed.

That being said, I recommend you look into this open source program

https://github.com/multiprocessio/dsq

It allows you to write essentially SQL Queries against an Excel Spreadsheet, so you could make a little batch script where you feed in an SKU and it returns a sheetname (or whatever part of the sheet would give you the Part that uses that SKU), and gives you a list of these.

I don't know that there is a good way to do this in Excel itself, apart from running like, a FIND ALL. But that just seems hokey.

I know you want to do without Arcane Coding, but this could be 10-20 lines of code, and SQL is rather simple.

Let me know if this doesn't work for you and I'll see if I can think of another way.

Comment: Wow, that looks great.  Thank you very much.

The more I think about it the less likely it seems to me there would be a way to get clean output in Excel alone.  This tool is an obvious solution (and I love the command line, I'm old school that way).

Sadly, I'm going to have to learn SQL to use this, but as you say it's not hard.  Prolly a lot of trial an error to get what I want.

Comment: @simonov Absolutely! and my pleasure. Don't forget to upvote my answer if it helped you :). Also, in terms of learning SQL, I'm not kidding it is easier than learning Excel formulas. I read the book Head First SQL which you can get used online for very cheap, or you can check out the https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ tutorial which is pretty decent. Good luck! message me if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'd upvote you if the system let me, but I don't have enough reputation or whatever to upvote answers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, without using complex code you can use the vlookup function, filter function and create a pivot table, about the details you can search on Google.